# Address box fails to be shown in the email

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was wondering if anyone could help me with my issue, When ever the form is submitted the street form does not show up in the email I receive. I don't understand why it might not be working I've looked through the php and JS but cant understand why it won't work. Here i the JS:

```
(function($){

$(document).ready(function() {

    /* ---------------------------------------------- /*
     * Contact form ajax
    /* ---------------------------------------------- */

    $('#contact-form').find('input,textarea').jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var submit          = $('#contact-form submit');
            var ajaxResponse    = $('#contact-response');

            var name            = $('#contact-form [name="name"]').val();
            var lastname        = $('#contact-form [name="lastname"]').val();
            var address         = $('#contact-form [name="address"]').val();
            var email           = $('#contact-form [name="email"]').val();
            var message         = $('#contact-form [name="message"]').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'assets/php/contact.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    lastname: lastname,
                    address: address, 
                    email: email,
                    message: message,
                },
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(result) {
                    submit.empty();
                    submit.append('<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i> Wait...');
                },
                success: function(result) {
                    if(result.sendstatus == 1) {
                        ajaxResponse.html(result.message);
                        $form.fadeOut(500);
                    } else {
                        ajaxResponse.html(result.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

});  })(jQuery);
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row">

                <div name="contactform" class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

                    <form  id="contact-form" method="post" novalidate>
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <label class="sr-only">First Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="name" placeholder="First Name" value="" required="">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <label  class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" value="" required="">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>

                           <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <label  class="sr-only">Address</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="address" placeholder="Address" value="" required="">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                <label class="sr-only">E-mail Address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" placeholder="E-mail Address" value="" required="">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>



                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control input-lg" rows="7" name="message" placeholder="Message - Please include Address and Telephone number" required=""></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>




                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-round btn-dark" >Send Email</button>
                            </div>

                        </div><!-- .row -->
                    </form>

                    <!-- Ajax response -->
                    <div id="contact-response" class="ajax-response text-center"></div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

And here is the php:

```
<?php
// Mail settings
$to      = "****@*******.co.uk";
$subject = "PB Enquiry Form - " . $_REQUEST['lastname'];

// You can put here your email
$header = "From:****@*******.co.uk\r\n";
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";

if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["lastname"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["message"])) {

    $content  = "First Name: "      . $_POST["name"]    . "\r\n";
    $content .= "Last Name: " . $_POST["lastname"]    . "\r\n";
    $content .= "Address: " . $_POST["address"]    . "\r\n";
    $content .= "Email: "     . $_POST["email"]   . "\r\n";
    $content .= "Message: "    . $_POST["message"]   . "\r\n";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $content, $header)) {
        $result = array(
            "message"    => "Thank you for contacting us.",
            "sendstatus" => 1
        );

        echo json_encode($result);
    } else {
        $result = array(
            "message"    => "Sorry, something is wrong.",
            "sendstatus" => 0
        );

        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out why it won't work and would be delighted if someone could help me.
If you do have a solution then please give an example of how to input the solution as I am new to the languages, Thank you!

Comment: Tightened up the code a bit so more would be seen in the viewport at once.

Comment: There is no field in the form named `address` - and you still expect to see it in the email ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV That was an error in the formatting of the question, it has now been resolved and any help on the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a tip: You know instead of `var name            = $('#contact-form [name="name"]').val();` etc etc and listing all the fields individually you could just execute .serialize() on the form to automatically get all the fields. Saves a lot of code, and also doesn't require maintenance if you add or remove fields. https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: As to your problem, at a glance the code looks like it should work. The address, if populated, should be included in the email. What debugging have you done? Go through each step of the process (getting the field data from the form, sending data in the ajax request, receiving in the POST variables, appending to the content string) and check the values of the relevant variable at each stage, so you can determine the point at which the data goes missing. Then we can narrow down our efforts to fixing that particular part of the code.

Comment: `var submit = $('#contact-form submit');` - there is no element with the tag name `submit` in your form, so this won’t select anything.

Comment: @CBroe So where would the submit variable have to go?

Comment: You are not sending this variable to the server - perhaps you wanted to target `#contact-form button[type="submit"]` ?

Comment: @CBroe true but the server takes no notice of this, the intention seems to be to use it only for displaying a "waiting" icon (in the beforeSend option). So it's not part of the problem as described.

Comment: @Lozy have you managed to do any of the debugging I suggested?

Comment: @ADyson As to what you've said I am rather new to all these languages and have just done minor adjustments to the code (which is from a template) to fit the new field and have so far not done any debugging.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid you need to do so, because the code as shown looks like it should work. Perhaps there is something non-obvious in there, or something strange in your environment which could cause the contents of the field not to show up in the email. But what we need to ensure is that the value entered into your form is being included in the email (i.e. in the $content variable). Work through the steps I suggested.

Comment: @ADyson Okay I will try my best to debug and go through the processes you have suggested, thank you. However I am not familiar with how to debug in  this case, any tips?

Comment: For the Javascript, use your browser's Developer Tools (press F12 on most desktop browsers). You can set breakpoints in your code, and read values printed to the console using any `console.log()` commands you choose to temporarily insert into the code. You can also use the Network tool to look into the AJAX request going to contact.php and see what values are sent in the body. Then in your PHP you can simply use temporary `var_dump()` statements to print the values of your variables. They'll end up in your ajax call's Response data - again use the network tool to check the output.

Comment: @ADyson So would I fill in the contact form and then submit it? while in developer tools? Also could the problem be with the JS being an older version on the server, as I have not checked whether it might be outdated.

Comment: yes you would open the developer tools, so you can see it alongside your page, and then fill in the form as normal and submit it. Regarding the JS, JS runs in the browser, it never goes anywhere near your server, so I'm not really sure what you mean by that. Are you talking about your version of jQuery or something?

Comment: @ADyson It shows me this in the console with a lot of errors. Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Comment: have you got google maps on your page somewhere? That error certainly has nothing to do with the code you've shown above.

Comment: @ADyson I didn't know what it was

Comment: @ADyson Also in the console when I submit it nothing shows up

Comment: you would have to look into the Network tab to see the ajax request, as I mentioned. And/Or set breakpoints in your code to stop on certain lines so you can examine the variable values, and/or add console.log() commands so it will send the variable values to the console. All the things I mentioned above.

Comment: Also, if you have existing errors in your console, you'll need to fix those before anything will work.

Comment: @ADyson How do I insert break points?

Comment: Normally you click on the line of code just to the left of it. Depends a bit on the browser tools. In IE for instance, you then have to press an extra button to start the debugger working. All the browsers have documentation online for their developer tools - check there, they will guidance on debugging and breakpoints.

Comment: @ADyson THank you for your help!

Comment: @ADyson However i cannot  find the contact.js file in the debugger

Comment: what browser are you using? All the files should normally be listed in the UI somewhere. Unless your app does some kind of bundling and/or minification of all the JS files before they're downloaded into the browser, so it's ended up being called something else? There's no way for me to know that based on the info you've provided so far.

Comment: @ADyson Mozilla Firefox

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/UI_Tour#Source_list_pane it should be listed like in the screenshot there

Comment: @ADyson With `var_dump()`where would I put it in the php? And would the fact that at the bottom of the HTML it a says:   `<!-- JAVASCRIPT FILES -->         
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>         
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>         
        <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>         
        <script src="assets/js/plugins.min.js"></script>         
        <script src="assets/js/custom.min.js"></script>`                                              But not the contact.js?

Comment: unless there are any other script tags elsewhere in your page, then that would indeed explain the absence of the contacts.js, yes. You do have to explicitly include a script in your page for it to be available. Do you really need the google maps one, btw? Are you actually using that for anything?

Comment: You can put the var_dump() statement(s) wherever you like, but a sensible place to put them would be just after you've set a variable, so you can see if it was set to the correct value. You have to give it the name of the variable you want to display e.g. `var_dump($_POST["address"]);` and `var_dump($content);` in the appropriate places would be useful in this case. http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: @ADyson Thanks again much appreciated!

Comment: @ADyson It seems as though because it wasn't listed at the bottom it was not working, so now it is but it seems to be sending two emails, any thoughts?

Comment: in that case, the first thing I would check is whether you're somehow sending two ajax requests for the same form

Comment: @ADyson Where in the code above would it be submitting anr ajax request?

Comment: `$.ajax({` ....your comment implies you didn't know it used AJAX???

Comment: @ADyson I knew it used AJAX I'm just not to familiar with AJAX requests

Comment: @ADyson Also one of the two emails has the address input field working and in the other not, any ideas?